# labelling a condition in LaTeX

Tags: cross-referencing, labels

I need to label two textual conditions in LaTeX. I found some hacks to make them label as equations, but what I want is something like this:

```
(D1) Some statement
(D2) Some other condition
```

I have these two conditions under itemize. Is there a consistent way to label and then later refer to these statements without numbering them as equation (1) and (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be best served by setting up a custom enumerated list using the machinery of the `enumitem` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} % for '\newlist' and '\setlist' macros
\newlist{condenum}{enumerate}{1} % 'condenum': a new, enumerate-like list env.
\setlist[condenum]{label=\bfseries Condition \arabic*., 
                   ref=\arabic*, wide}
\begin{document}
The following conditions apply:
\begin{condenum}
\item Some statement. \label{cond:some}
\item Some other statement.
\end{condenum}

\noindent
A cross-reference to Condition~\ref{cond:some}.
\end{document}
```

If you want the condition labels to look like `(D1)`, `(D2)`, etc., simply change `label=\bfseries Condition \arabic*.` to `label=(D\arabic*)`.

Comment: Thats lovely. May I suggest adding the little modification for future visitors? You can actually customize condenum while calling it because of versatility of enumitem package. I can produce output like (D1) at one call and (T1) at other call.

Comment: @VishalGupta - Indeed, the `enumitem` package makes it very straightforward to customize its environments, but up front and "on the fly" later on in the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following coding with the package "enumitem" for your requirement:

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(D\arabic*)]
    \item\label{d1} Some statement cross reference: \ref{d1}    
    \item\label{d2} Some other condition cross reference: \ref{d2}
\end{enumerate}
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does your suggested solution require the use of any LaTeX packages? If so, which ones?

Comment: No need of any packages.

Comment: Are you sure? The `[label=(D\arabic*)]` code snippet would appear to be in conflict with the default (LaTeX) definition of the `enumerate` environment.

Comment: Sorry!!! enumitem package used.

Comment: You should post fully compilable code rather than code snippets. "Fully compilable" means, in practice, something that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @Mico Thank you very much for your Guidance. Heeafter i will follow this way.